# What is causing "No non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf"?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a function which will draw specific lines on my plot, defined as

```
MaxLines <- function(df,df_col_1,df_col_2){
  data.frame(df_col_1 = c(rep(df$df_col_1[which.max(df$df_col_2)], 2),
                                           -Inf), 
                       df_col_2 = c(-Inf, rep(max(df$df_col_2), 2)))
  
}
```

When I try to call this function I get the error mentioned in the title.

```
col_1 = c(5,6,7)
col_2 = c(1,2,3)
foo <- data.frame(col_1,col_2)
MaxLines(foo,col_1,col_2)


------------------------------------------------
new_1 new_2
1  -Inf  -Inf
2  -Inf  -Inf
3  -Inf  -Inf
Warning message:
In max(df$df_col_2) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

I expect the function to return

| col_1 | col_2 |
| --- | --- |
| 7 | -Inf |
| 7 | 3 |
| -Inf | 3 |

But it does not. When inputting into the function directly ie.

```
MaxLines <- data.frame(col_1 = c(rep(foo$col_1[which.max(foo$col_2)], 2),
                                           -Inf), 
                       col_2 = c(-Inf, rep(max(foo$col_2), 2)))
```

I get the correct output, so it seems to just be the calling of the function.

Comment: It's a typo: you are trying to access a column named `df_col_1` but the actual column name is `col_1` (and the same for the other column). — But you are also not using the `df_col_1` and `df_col_2` function arguments. So it's possible that I misunderstood your intent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Base R functions don't easily allow you to pass in unquoted column names. You can either convert the symbols to strings

```
MaxLines <- function(df,df_col_1,df_col_2){
  df_col_1<-as.character(substitute(df_col_1))
  df_col_2<-as.character(substitute(df_col_2))
  data.frame(df_col_1 = c(rep(df[[df_col_1]][which.max(df[[df_col_2]])], 2),
                          -Inf), 
             df_col_2 = c(-Inf, rep(max(df[[df_col_2]]), 2)))
  
}
MaxLines(foo,col_1,col_2)
```

or you can pass in strings

```
MaxLines <- function(df,df_col_1,df_col_2){
  data.frame(df_col_1 = c(rep(df[[df_col_1]][which.max(df[[df_col_2]])], 2),
                          -Inf), 
             df_col_2 = c(-Inf, rep(max(df[[df_col_2]]), 2)))
  
}
MaxLines(foo,"col_1","col_2")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution: you're repeating column names and arguments, so if you change your function to this, it works:

```
    MaxLines <- function(df,col1,col2){
  data.frame(df_col_1 = c(rep(df[[col1]][which.max(df[[col2]])], 2),
                          -Inf), 
             df_col_2 = c(-Inf, rep(max(df[[col2]]), 2)))
  
}
```

Output:

```
MaxLines(foo,'col_1','col_2')

# df_col_1 df_col_2
# 1        7     -Inf
# 2        7        3
# 3     -Inf        3
```

Comment: If you do this, it doesn't matter what you pass to the `col_1` and `col_2` arguments. You'll always get the same value as just doing `MaxLines(foo)`. Try `MaxLines(foo,apple,banana)`

Comment: New iteration will only work with correctly specified column names, but using columns as strings

Comment: That should work now, but it also exactly what I already included in my answer.

Comment: Haha, good point, didn't notice. At least yours is the accepted answer (: